# Regex to just get new line after a match and ignore everything else

Tags: regex, power-automate

In need for some help, please.

Tried a bunch of Regex and also tried some adaptions to get the desired result, but failed.
Sample Data:

```
CAR
VW
MODEL
ARTEON
BHP
200
```

I want to grab, for example, "VW" or "ARTEON" (just one). So, after a string, the regex should find a new line, get everything from it and ignore everything after it.

I have tried:

```
(?<=MODEL[\r\n]).+[^\r\n]
(?<=MODEL\n)[^\r\n]+
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Try `(?<=MODEL[\r\n]+).+`, or `(?<=MODEL\r\n).+`

Comment: Hum, they don't seem to work.
I found this one: \bMODEL\s+(\S+), but also grabs the MODEL with some lines between the actual model. Any ideas?

Comment: Do `CAR[\r\n]([^\r\n]+)` and `MODEL[\r\n]([^\r\n]+)` not work? Which "flavour" of regex does power-automate use? Also, look at the pattern you wrote: you placed parentheses around the `MODEL` part, even though that's not the part you want.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's .NET, according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/text#:~:text=a%20regular%20expression.-,To%20find%20more%20information%20about%20regular%20expressions%2C%20go%20to%20Regular%20Expression%20Language%20%2D%20Quick%20Reference.,-Additionally%2C%20you%20can).

Comment: So try `(?<=\bMODEL\s+)\S+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how does that capture the part _after_ "CAR" or "MODEL"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Lookbehind pattern does not consume the `MODEL` and whitespaces after it.

Comment: But why use look-behind at all? Won't it run slower than a normal stateless DFA regex?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update your existing regex to have an or condition for the car and the model, then add a named capture group to identify the match for the car and the model. The named capture group can help you select which of the match you want to get (or you may also use the index of the match)

Please check the regex101 link below for the explanation:

https://regex101.com/r/2ueSPk/1

```
(?<car>(?<=CAR[\r\n]).+[^\r\n])|(?<model>(?<=MODEL[\r\n]).+[^\r\n])
```

Comment: Why `.+[^\r\n]`? `.` doesn't match `\r` and `\n` by default. Do you mean `.{2,}`?

Comment: @Lorvin de la Cruz
I thank you both for the help. Although they don't seem to work.
In the following image ( https://ibb.co/HTVknWC ) there's a screenshot of what's happening.
1 - The preview seems to work for some Regex
2 - The selectors with the regex
3 - final Excel table, where only the 3rd regex seems to produce some results, although it keeps the model word and some new lines and spaces between the actual model.
Any ideas?